# What's the difference between assigning a function with and without parentheses?

Tags: python

What's the difference in python between

```
value = getValue()
```

and

```
value = getValue
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using parenthesis calls the function where as not using them creates a reference to that function.

See below:

```
>>> def t():
...     return "Hi"
...
>>> a = t
>>> a
<function t at 0x01BECA70>
>>> a = t()
>>> a
'Hi'
>>>
```

Here is a good link to explain further: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html  (scroll down to the "defining functions" part).

Comment: And in the first case, you call `a()` to get `'Hi'`

Answer (score 5):

`value = getValue()` is a function call and assignment of the return value. It means "call function `getValue` with no arguments and make `value` refer to whatever it `return`s".

`value = getValue` says "make `value` refer to the same function that `getValue` refers to".